# How to implement neural-network with vector(1x160) inputs and output vector(1x6)

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

I'm trying to understand how to implement a neural network with 160 inputs and 6 outputs. Inputs and outputs are time-series, so this is not about classification. I decided to use perceptron with 3 hidden layers, but I don't know how to implement this using python. Could you help me with links to such projects or how to adopt a classification problem to time series?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors/problems are you facing?

Comment: How to convert the outputs that after the network will lie in the range from 0 to 1 to the actual values of the outputs. In my case, it is necessary to predict the temperature value in 6 sensors, the temperature is in [134,139] C.

Comment: Please see the guide on providing an example and code to work with - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve